# Determining if a number is a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider $$ x = \frac{4^{99}\cdot7 - 1}{3} $$

Is $x$ prime ? Why not ? I tried the divisibility criteria, but I can't find a way. I'm currently dabbling in number theory, but I got stuck on this one. Any ideas?

Comment: Where does the problem come from?

Comment: I suppose you're not allowed to use a computer? (No, it's not prime, but its smallest prime factor is 367, so trial division will probably not work.)

Comment: Well, I don't really want to use a computer, I'm interested if this can be done using theoretical tools. This is taken from a college textbok in our  university's library

Comment: may be hint :$$x=\frac{7*4^{99}-1}{3}=\\\frac{7*4^{99}-7+6}{3}=\\\frac{7(*4^{99}-1)}{3}+\frac{6}{3}\\\frac{7}{3}(4-1)(4^{98}+4^{97}+4^{96}+...4^1+1)+\space 2\\7(4^{98}+4^{97}+4^{96}+...4^1+1) +\space 2=\\7(4^{98}+4^{97}+4^{96}+...4^1)+7 +\space 2=\\\rightarrow x=7(4^{98}+4^{97}+4^{96}+...4^1) +\space 9$$

Answer (score 1):

The prime $367$ is pulled out of a hat, but this solves the problem.

Use [Euler's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) and [quadratic reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity).

$7\cdot 2^{15}\equiv 7\cdot 1024\cdot 32\equiv 7\cdot  -77\cdot 32\equiv -7^2\cdot 352$

$\equiv -7^2\cdot -15\equiv 7\cdot 105\equiv 735\equiv 1\pmod{\! 367}$

$7\cdot 4^{99}-1\equiv 7\cdot 2^{15}\cdot 2^{183}-1\equiv \left(\frac{2}{367}\right)-1\equiv 0\pmod{\! 367}$

Comment: I know you just said that $367$ 'is pulled out of a hat', but I'm really wondering what's the intuition, or rather the reason behind this choice. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

A loose method
$$
4^{99}7+(6-7) = =\left(4^{99}-1\right)7 +6 = \left(2^{99\cdot 2}-1\right)7 +6
$$
thus we have
$$
\frac{\left(2^{99\cdot 2}-1\right)7 +6}{3} = \frac{\left(2^{3^2\cdot 11\cdot 2}-1\right)7}{3} + 2
$$
since we now have the form of a Mersenne number $2^n-1$ we can use the fact to determine that we have a composite number.

The important steps still open is to determine if $M_{198}\equiv 0\,  \text{mod 3}$. Also, is the result a prime or not.